# NPE in ModelAttribute while sending empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm experiencing problem with feign client (spring-boot-starter 2.4.4, spring-cloud-starter-openfeign 3.0.2). When I'm trying to send an empty list inside @ModelAttribute annotated object feign client throws feign.codec.EncodeException with NullPointerException cause. Problem does not occur when list has at least one element.

Does anybody know how to properly override feign encoder to enable passing empty list without errors?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a class that implements the feign Encoder (https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/codec/Encoder.java)

e.g.

```
public class EnableEmptyListEncoder implements Encoder {
   @Override
   public void encode(Object object, Type bodyType, RequestTemplate template) {
    // empty list encode logic here 
   }
}
```

How you point to that encoder depends on your setup:

-- via the application.yml:

```
feign:
    client:
        config:
            feignName:
                encoder: com.example.EnableEmptyListEncoder
```

-- via  a buider:

```
Feign.builder()
    .encoder( new EnableEmptyListEncoder()  )
```

-- a bean in the config class

```
@Bean
public EnableEmptyListEncoder encoder() {
    return new EnableEmptyListEncoder();
}
```